# Stackdriver in GKE throws rpc error "Failed to export to Stackdriver" "context deadline exceeded"

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

I see the following two lines in my GKE Cluster logs from my golang app containers. The error is intermittent (few errors every couple of days). I have been unable to find much information on it.

```
Failed to export to Stackdriver: rpc error = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded

rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
```

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, docker or kubelet health check might be failing. This will cause the node to flap between NotReady and Ready.

Using a Cloud Logging query like:

```
resource.type="k8s_node"
log_id("kubelet")
resource.labels.node_name=""
(
"Container runtime docker failed!"
OR
"Kubelet is unhealthy!"
OR
"Force shutdown daemon"
)
```

The logline posted shows a docker container killed by the health-monitor script that is run by systemd based on [this](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/release-1.11/cluster/gce/gci/node.yaml#L43-L61).

The role of this script is to check if docker is healthy by running `docker ps`. If this command fails or doesn't return in a reasonable time then `dockerd` is killed using `SIGUSR1`. This will leave on the node the following files that could be used to troubleshoot the issue:

```
/run/docker/daemon-data-<TIMESTAMP>.log
/run/docker/goroutine-stacks-<TIMESTAMP>.log
```

Note that the container startup was slow because of a combination of the node being overloaded and the container requesting very little CPU.

(cfr. `kubectl explain pod.spec.containers.resources.requests.cpu`).

Comment: Tried out checking the kubelet logs but didn't find any such errors. I suspect this issue is in the opencensus golang library https://github.com/census-instrumentation/opencensus-go that the context is closed before the data goes through, maybe batching too big